# Dashcode xml problem

Tags: xcode, macos, dashcode

I am new to dashcode app development. I am trying to learn RSS iphone application. I have made a RSS feed at my site. The following is the code for the xml file. In interner explorer on the pc it is showing that my rss is working but dashcode is giving error and does not show the content of the feed. The xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Webzians Library</title>
<link>http://www.webzians.com</link>
<description>website building and design</description>
<generator>Notepad</generator>
<item>
<title>First Item</title>
<link>http://www.webzians.com/first.html</link>
<description>this is first item</description>
</item>
<item>
<title>Second Item</title>
<link>http://www.webzians.com/Second.html</link>
<description>this is Second item</description>
</item>
<item>
<title>Third Item</title>
<link>http://www.webzians.com/third.html</link>
<description>this is third item</description>
</item>
<item>
<title>Fourth Item</title>
<link>http://www.webzians.com/fourth.html</link>
<description>this is fourth item</description>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

please help

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified any namespaces in your XML.

The simplest way to fix this is probably to find some other RSS and take the namespaces from that :) Or your could consult the [RSS specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html).